# PHP - Session ID changes when I post a form or refresh page

Tags: php, session

The problem is that when I refresh page, the session ID changes.

Also, when I clic on "Next Page" and arrive on the "Page 2", the session_id has changed. So if I clic on "Previous Page" and arrive on "Page 1", I realize that `$_SESSION['a']` and `$_SESSION['b']` are `NULL`.

In addition, if I clic on the previous page button of my browser, I arrive on the old "Page 1", with the old session_id and `$_SESSION['a']` and `$_SESSION['b']` have the values that I 've posted.

If I run the code from the localhost, there is no problem.
The problem appears when I run as a client and the code is on the server.

I 've googled the problem, I 've seen answers but I haven't find a solution yet.

Here is my code:

**page_1.php:**

```
<?php 

session_start();

if (!$_POST){

    $a = $_SESSION['a'];
    $b = $_SESSION['b'];
}

elseif ($_POST){

    $a = $_POST['a'];
    $b = $_POST['b'];   
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

if ( $_POST and $a and $b ){

    $_SESSION['a'] = $a;
    $_SESSION['b'] = $b;

    echo '<script language="JavaScript">
        self.location="page_2.php";
        </script>';
}


?>


<html>
<body>
<form action="page_1.php" method=post>

<?php

      echo $_SESSION['a'];
      echo $_SESSION['b'];
      echo session_id().' | '.session_name(); ?>

<!--
...(html code)... 
-->

<tr>
    <td><input type='submit' name='p1_submit' value="Next Page >>"></td>
</tr>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**page_2.php:**

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!$_POST){

    $c = $_SESSION['c'];
    $d = $_SESSION['d'];

}

elseif ($_POST){    

    $c = $_POST['c'];
    $d = $_POST['d'];

}   


if ($_POST and $c and $d)
    {

    $_SESSION['c'] = $c;
    $_SESSION['d'] = $d;


    echo '  <script language="JavaScript">
            self.location="page_3.php";
        </script>';
    }


?>


<html>

<body>

<form action="page_2.php" method=post>

<?php echo session_id().' | '.session_name(); ?>

<!--
...(html code)... 
-->

<tr>
    <td><button type="button" onclick="location.href='page_1.php';">Previous Page</button><input type='submit' name='p2_submit' value="Next Page >>"></td>
</tr>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this syntax correct `$_POST and $c and $d`?

Comment: @Swellar yes ~ http://php.net/manual/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: You can use `and`, `&&`, `or`, `||` .

Comment: Are the sessions started correctly? You can check the return value of `session_start()` to check that. And make sure errors and warnings are displayed while you are developing.

Comment: @Phil I know the usage of `AND`, what I was curious about is specifically this line: `and $a and $b`. What kind of check is being done here? Is it if those two have any value or not?

Comment: @Swellar http://php.net/manual/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the info

Comment: @jeroen how can I check that?

Comment: @Phil and Swellar It checks if those values have posted. If not it doesn't change page and warns the user that they are null. I know that it works well

Comment: Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

OK I am answering the question myself.

I solved the problem by adding a start page before Page 1.

**start.php:**

```
<?php 

session_start();

echo '<script language="JavaScript">
        self.location="page_1.php";
        </script>';

?>
```